# Sorting custom object by private members

Tags: c++, class, sorting, private

I found a lot of explanations on sorting functions, but I could not manage to implement one with my code.

I have a structure like this:

```
class Out{
  public:
     const std::map<std::string,In>& getListIn()const;
  private:
     std::map<std::string,In> listIn;

     class In{
        public:
           const float& getScore();
        private :
              float score;
     };
};
```

I want to sort my `listIn` by score (max to min). I tried to overload `operator>` or to create my own function:

```
 std::map<std::string,Out::In> notVisited = listIn;
 bool Out::In::compareCostScore (const std::pair<std::string,Out::In>& v1,const std::pair<std::string,Out::In>& v2){
        return (v1.second.getCostScore() > v2.second.getCostScore());
 }
 std::sort(notVisited.begin(), notVisited.end(), Out::In::compareCostScore());
```

But the function is not known.
Or :

```
std::sort(notVisited.begin(), notVisited.end(),[] (const std::map<std::string,Out::In>& v1, const std::map<std::string,Out::In>& v2) {return (v1.second.getCostScore() < v2.second.getCostScore()};)
```

I'm having some problems with compatibility of type or privacy. Maybe that's because I'm trying to sort this private member out of the class...
Thanks

**Edit:**
I made it \o/ :

```
bool operator > (const In& v) const{
                return (score > v.score);
}
std::vector<Out::In> notVisited;
for( std::map<std::string,Out::In>::iterator it = listIn.begin(); it != listIn.end(); ++it ) {
    notVisited.push_back( it->second );
}
std::sort(notVisited.begin(), notVisited.end(), std::greater<Out::In>());
```

Thanks for your explications about map

Comment: `In` should probably be public since you are exposing it outside of `Out` through the `getListIn` function.

Comment: ok, this will certainly simplify my script. Edit : I never used getListIn, It was just in case I nedd it for the sort

Comment: You can't sort a `map`.

Comment: Just for clarity, *where's the "list" you're trying to sort*.? Your maps are already sorted (by their comparators). If you want an alternate sorting, either you need a different map or a *sequence* container sent through `std::sort`. Maps are *associative* containers.

Comment: ah.. I did not know that I cannot sort a map. So maybe I should convert my map listIn to a vector notVisited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your inner class has only one field and it has a getter (you might want to make this getter const `const float& getScore() const` ) you can simply change `Out::in` declaration to `public` and get rid of the problem. But if it is an extract and there are more logic after `Out::in` that you want to hide from public access then you can define your comparator as a friend function like this:

```
class Out{
/* ... */
public:
    friend bool Out::In::compareCostScore (const std::pair<std::string,Out::In>& v1,const std::pair<std::string,Out::In>& v2);
}
```

Comment: I just copy a small part of my script, I have more members, functions, etc.
As I copy my map in another list (because I need to remove some element, temporary), I should change the type, to a vector or something else ?